# Cannot get file (image/video) to upload to Google Photos using the Google Photos Api

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-photos-api

I have literally tried all I can think of at this point. Been working on this all weekend. I am using NextJs to upload an image or video to Google Photos. The upload token always returns a token. Using the batchCreate call I have been able to upload one file type which is a `.mov` file. Everything else has failed and even that while returning successful never shows up in the album I specified in google photos, which is an album that my app, webpage, created via the API. Using the same code, uploading a png or jpg or another video file type fails. I have tried creating `FormData` and appending the file to that and passing that in as the body. Used all sorts of FileReader functions. `readAsBinaryString` `readAsArrayBuffer` `readAsDataURI` none seem to upload the file correctly and the api errors are not worth anything because they are obviously incorrect, they should offer a validateUploadToken call which could be quite useful. Has anyone done this successfully? Here is a spattering of code I am using.

Converter code to convert a file to anything I need it to be

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles: File[]) => {
    const file = acceptedFiles[0];
    const r = new FileReader();
    let result: Record<string, any> = {};
    r.onload = (e) => {
      onUpdate({
        bytes: e.target?.result ?? "",
        fileName: file.name,
        mimeType: file.type,
      });
    };
    r.readAsBinaryString(file);
}, []);
```

Here is the api call code for calling to get an upload token.

```
export async function uploadMediaItemGoogle(
  accessToken: string,
  uploadMediaItem: UploadMediaItem
) {
  const url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads";
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "X-Goog-Upload-File-Name": uploadMediaItem.fileName,
      "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol": "raw",
      "X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type": uploadMediaItem.mimeType,
      "X-Goog-Upload-Raw-Size": uploadMediaItem.bytes.length,
    } as any,
    body: uploadMediaItem.bytes,
    method: "POST",
  });
  const uploadResponse = await response.text();
  if (uploadResponse) {
    const createResponse = await createMediaItem(
      accessToken,
      uploadMediaItem,
      uploadResponse
    );
    return createResponse;
  }
}
```

The batchCreate call to create the media item

```
export async function createMediaItem(
  accessToken: string,
  uploadMediaItem: UploadMediaItem,
  uploadToken: string
) {
  const url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate";
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      albumId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHARED_ALBUM_ID!,
      newMediaItems: [
        {
          description: uploadMediaItem.description,
          simpleMediaItem: {
            fileName: uploadMediaItem.fileName,
            uploadToken,
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
    method: "POST",
  });
  const mediaItem = await response.json();
  return mediaItem;
}
```

The code that actually calls the functions that are calling the api

```
const [uploadMediaItem, setUploadMediaItem] = useState<UploadMediaItem>({
    description: "",
    fileName: "",
    message: "",
    mimeType: "",
    bytes: null,
  });

async function callApi(token: string) {
    setUploadingMediaItem(true);
    const uploadRes = await uploadMediaItemGoogle(token, uploadMediaItem);
    if (uploadRes) {
      console.log({ uploadRes });
    }
}

  function onUploadMediaItem() {
    if (accessToken && !loadingAccessToken) {
      try {
        callApi(accessToken);
        setUploadProgress(null);
        setUploadingMediaItem(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

If helpful this is what the api is returning after the batch create call

```
{
    "uploadRes": {
        "newMediaItemResults": [
            {
                "uploadToken": "CAIS6QIAJoFQir42ld+rMy3IIpcNj7DjC3oshob6efr37YBscj... the rest is redacted",
                "status": {
                    "code": 3,
                    "message": "Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried this code and have set the body to each one of these values specified in the keys of this object, but none of them worked either

```
// none of this code worked, but I gave it a healthy try
    
    export async function returnFileAsBinary(file: File) {
      const toBinString = (bytes: any) =>
        bytes.reduce(
          (str: any, byte: { toString: (arg0: number) => string }) =>
            str + byte.toString(2).padStart(8, "0"),
          ""
        );
      const r = new FileReader();
      const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
      let result: Record<string, any> = {};
      r.onload = (e) => {
        result.arrayBuffer = arrayBuffer;
        result.bufferFrom = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
        result.binString = toBinString(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
        result.buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString("binary");
        result.base64Img = e.target?.result as string;
        // result.binaryImg = convertDataURIToBinary(result.base64Img);
        result.blob = new Blob([result.binaryImg], { type: file.type });
        result.blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(result.blob);
        result.binaryString = e.target?.result ?? "";
      };
      r.readAsBinaryString(file);
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: `FileReader.readAsBinaryString` method might not be the best way to read the file for upload. Instead, haven't you tried `readAsArrayBuffer` and then convert the buffer to a `Uint8Array` before sending it in the request body...

Comment: Good sir. You are fantastic. I had tried converting, but I wonder if trying to convert from a binary string or a dataURI was adding extra characters. That finally did the job. Thank you so much.